# Confirm only does else part of the code

Tags: javascript, php

So the script below for some reason only does else part of the code no matter if I confirm during prompt.
Update the whole function that leads to this confirmation prompt without confirm function  header('refresh: 0; url=new_items.php?Patch_No='.$patch.''); works as it is supposed to.

```
     public function save_champions($champion, $noofspellschamp, $patch, $champ_number, $champnospellno, $spellicon, $spelltitle, $change, $description){
                include '../DBconnection_patches.php';

                $sql ='';
                $sql ="INSERT INTO info (Patch_No)
                        VALUES ('".$patch."')";
                $conn->query($sql);
                for($i = 1; $i<=$champ_number; $i++){
                    $sql = 
                    "INSERT INTO champions (Patch_No, Champion)
                    VALUES (
                        '".$patch."',
                        '".$champion[$i]."'
                    )";
                    $conn->query($sql);

                    for($j=1; $j<=$noofspellschamp[$i]; $j++){
                        switch($spellicon[$i][$j]){
                            case 'Passive':
                            $sql = "UPDATE champions SET Passive='".$spelltitle[$i][$j]."' WHERE Champion='".$champion[$i]."' AND Patch_No='".$patch."'";
                            $conn->query($sql);
                            break;
                            case 'Q':
                            $sql = "UPDATE champions SET Q='".$spelltitle[$i][$j]."' WHERE Champion='".$champion[$i]."' AND Patch_No='".$patch."'";
                            $conn->query($sql);
                            break;
                            case 'W':
                            $sql = "UPDATE champions SET W='".$spelltitle[$i][$j]."' WHERE Champion='".$champion[$i]."' AND Patch_No='".$patch."'";
                            $conn->query($sql);
                            break;
                            case 'E':
                            $sql = "UPDATE champions SET E='".$spelltitle[$i][$j]."' WHERE Champion='".$champion[$i]."' AND Patch_No='".$patch."'";
                            $conn->query($sql);
                            break;
                            case 'R':
                            $sql = "UPDATE champions SET R='".$spelltitle[$i][$j]."' WHERE Champion='".$champion[$i]."' AND Patch_No='".$patch."'";
                            $conn->query($sql);
                            break;
                        }
                        for($k=1;$k<=$champnospellno[$i][$j];$k++){
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO spells (Patch_No, Champion, Spell_Change, Spell_Change_Icon, Spell_Type)
                                VALUES(
                                '".$patch."',
                                '".$champion[$i]."',

                                '".$description[$i][$j][$k]."',
                                '".$change[$i][$j][$k]."',
                                '".$spellicon[$i][$j]."'
                                )";
                                $conn->query($sql);
                        }
                    }
                }

                echo $conn->error;
                if(empty($conn->error)){
                    echo '<script>

                    if (confirm("Champions saved. Do you wish to create items page?")== true) {
                        ';
                        header('refresh: 0; url=new_items.php?Patch_No='.$patch.'');
                    echo '} else {';
                        header('refresh: 0; url=../index.php');
                    echo '}
                    </script>';
                    exit;
                    //

                }
            }
```

Comment: i dont understand your question?

Comment: please update your question with the post-rendered script block as it appears on the client side.

Comment: confirm function is javascripts prompt with OK and Cancel and no matter if I click OK or Cancel ill get redirected to that index.php which is in else {}

Comment: The whole idea is wrong, there is no conditional PHP code evaluation based on JS

Comment: @Higeath i understand what you are saying, but this is not what i asked. please post in your question the script block that this code generates. i want to see it exactly how it appears on the client machine please.

Comment: @Banana Could you help me out how to attach script block and where can I look for it? I'm going through Chrome's inspection element and can't really find it

Comment: @Higeath right-click your document and view source. find the script block there, and just edit your question and paste it in.

Comment: The code suffers several design and security issues, i.e. the `switch` is not necessary, it duplicates code, you could build the query instead. The `Patch_No` - anyone can edit the url, google for *sql injection*.

Comment: The part in question, the `if` clause containing `confirm`, looks fine. It's possible something in the `header` function, which you didn't show, is causing issues. Could you show us that function and/or, preferably, the generated script? You can find all scripts by typing `document.querySelectorAll("script")` in the console.

Comment: @redbmk did that which showed me nothing just [] I deleted  header('refresh: 0; url=../index.php'); part and it redirected me to the correct part but now clicking cancel will also redirect you to the same site

Comment: oic, `header` is a built in php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to mix your php and javascript code. If you want to redirect based on user input, you should do the whole redirection in javascript. In PHP you're writing a header telling the page to redirect, then telling it to redirect to a different page.

```php
if(empty($conn->error)){
    echo "<script>
        if (confirm(\"Champions saved. Do you wish to create items page?\")) {
            window.location = \"new_items.php?Patch_No=$patch\";
        } else {
            window.location = \"../index.php\";
        }
    </script>";
    exit;
}
```